# Why is this bountied question not in the featured section?

Tags: support, bounties

Why is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43768141/openid-and-restful-api?noredirect=1#comment74683519_43768141) not in the featured section?

It currently has a bounty open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is now:

[image]

When you feature it, the server probably took a while to actually feature your question. This is the same effect as posting your question but not *immediately* seeing your question in the list of newest questions. Nothing strange here.

In other words: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/